# pg_ctl: no database directory specified and environment variable PGDATA unset

Tags: sql, postgresql, windows, windows-10

When I run the command `pg restart` on Windows 10, I get the below error:

```
pg_ctl: no database directory specified and environment variable PGDATA unset
```

Why? How to solve it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to specify where the database directory is installed to.

eg

```
pg_ctl restart -D [insert directory location here]
```

Failing that you will need to set the environment variable PGDATA. 
Something like

```
 set $PGDATA = [directory location here]
```

Comment: I tried that but pg_ctl STATUS came back with the same error

Comment: 'pg restart' should be 'pg_ctl restart'

Comment: after command

  `./pg_ctl restart -D  /usr/local/var/postgres`
I got error

`pg_ctl: directory "/usr/local/var/postgres" is not a database cluster directory`

Comment: @Mist Where is your data directory ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set an environment variable to point where your database directory is at,
for example:
`setx PGDATA D:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\data`

Answer (score 1):

In MacOS

```
$ sudo -u postgres
$ ps -f -u postgres  # should list postgres processes 

$./pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/13/data restart
```

Comment: For some reason, I had to combine the `sudo -u` and `pg_ctl`. Full command that worked for me was: `sudo -u postgres pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/13/data restart`

Answer (score 0):

As a last resort you can also try a re-install:

```
brew services stop postgres
brew uninstall --force postgres
brew install postgresql
brew services start postgres
```